# extract records between given start and end time from multiple log files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

we have log files that would be having million records in format :

xyz,xyz,**YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**,....,

we will get starttime and endtime in format : **YYYYMMDDHHMMSS** as input to the shellscript.
we want to extract records from all the log files whose timestamp is between starttime and endtime.

Single record in log : abc,def,ghi,**2018-06-03 11:00:00**,...,xyz

wrapper script : xyz.sh '20180603112000' '20180604120000'

Expected Output : all records that are between given two timestamps.

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly add sample(s) of input and expected output in your post with CODE TAGS along with your effort(which you made to fulfill your requirement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

d4="([0-9]{4})"
d2="([0-9]{2})"
pattern="$d4$d2$d2$d2$d2$d2"
replace='\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6'
from=$(echo "$1" | sed -r "s/$pattern/$replace/")
to=$(echo "$2" | sed -r "s/$pattern/$replace/")

sed -n "/$from/,\$p;/$to/q" file
```

In plain English it is inclusive the first match of $from and inclusive the first line to match $to.

Specifically, the script first converts the input to timestamps expected to occur in the file. Then sed iterates the file without printing by default (-n), but print everything from the first line to match $from up to the last line($), however if $to is encountered, sed will quit.

This solution is not perfect though. It works on the assumption that every second contains at least one log line. Or at least the seconds searched on. Generally, you would not be required to extract log lines by the second and I would recommend extracting chunks by the hour or minute. Unless, of course, you have a crazy amount of log lines in which case I would think this assumption holds. Second, it assumes that the data in the log lines does not contain any timestamps. If the data itself contains timestamps, then this functionality could break.

**Update:**
I didn't really like the solution I gave, since it prints only the first line matching $to.
It was easy to make, but probably not what you want.
Here is a solution that stops right before the first line matching $to:

```
sed -n "/$from/,\$p" file | sed "/$to/Q"
```

You can do it with a single sed call, but it is a little harder to understand:

```
sed -n "/$from/,\${/$to/Q;p}" file
```

And here is a solution for including all of the lines matching $to

```
sed -n "/$from/,\$p" file | sed "/$to/{/$to/{N};q}"
```

Explanation of the new parts: Q will quit before autoprint, 
but since I used p for printing I had to make sure Q fires before p `/$to/Q;p`,
or use a separate sed invocation for a more easy to understand solution.

The second solution simply autoprints until it encounters $to `/$to/`.
Then it appends every subsequent line matching $to to patspace `/$to/{N}`.
The final `q` prints patspace and quits sed.

Comment: Thanks @Erik Lievaart, for your first as well as updated post :) we wil be extracing chunks based on hours and minutes , and also to update you , there will not be any data in loglines containing timestamps other then the field we are matching.

Comment: This approach has one issue, it does not work if there is no timestamp mactching input starttime.

Comment: That is correct, it is the reason I suggested filtering on hours (or minutes). Which would make the situation less likely. If you want a solution that is foolproof, then sed is probably not the tool for the job (since you need to interpret the timestamps, rather than doing simple text matches). In which case I would suggest using a full blown programming language. However, you would be making a trade off between exactness and performance. The sed solution is extremely efficient.

Comment: Ah, I just realized that my intentions might not be as clear as I though they were. A further clarification: if you adjust the script so that the seconds (or possibly minutes) are not part of the expressions filtered by sed, then the filtering will work as long as there is a log record matching the starting minute (or hour). Since the expression is currently defined all the way up to the seconds, there needs to be a log record that exact second. Dropping the precision of the sed expression drastically improves the usability of this solution.